# Twig templates don't show updates. Symfony 4.3

Tags: php, symfony, twig

After I edit my twig templates, they don't load on the page.

I have a header and footer twig file which are included in my **base.html.twig**.
When i edit these files, the changes aren't pushed trough when i reload the page.
I've tried clearing the cache and i disabled cache in **config\packages\twig.yaml**

I even tried to completely delete the cache folder, nothing seems to work.

I use the built in Symfony server.

homepageController.php:

```
?php
    
    namespace App\Controller;
    
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
    
    use App\Entity\Vacature;
    
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    class HomepageController extends AbstractController
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="homepage")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $rep = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Vacature::class);
            $data1 = $rep->getAllVacatures();
            $data2 = $rep->getLastVacatures(5);
    
            return array("carousel" => $data1, "laatste5" => $data2);
        }
    }
```

Homepage/index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello HomepageController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% for vacature in carousel %}
    <div class="vacature">
        <h4>{{ vacature.titel }}</h4>
        <p>{{ vacature.tekst }}
        <a href="{{ path('vacature', { "id": vacature.id}) }}">Bekijk</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% for vacature in laatste5 %}
    <div class="vacature">
        <h4>{{ vacature.titel }}</h4>
        <p>{{ vacature.tekst }}
        <a href="{{ path('vacature', { "id": vacature.id}) }}">Bekijk</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<pre>
    {{ dump(carousel) }}
</pre>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}VacIT{% endblock %}</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('/assets/css/foundation.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="{{ asset('/assets/css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='header'>
            {% include "header.html.twig" %}
        </div>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
        <div id='footer'>
            {% include "footer.html.twig" %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

header.html.twig

```
<div class='header'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <div class='header-logo'>
                <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">
                    <img  id='logo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/logo/logo.png') }}" alt="logo" width="200px">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="skew-header-shadow">
                <div class="skew-header"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

footer.html.twig

```
<div class="footer-box">
    <div class="skew-footer-shadow">
        <div class="skew-footer"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">
            <img  id='logo' src="{{ asset('/assets/images/logo/logo.png') }}" alt="logo" width="300px">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the tree is

```
Project
|-bin 
|-config
|-public
   |-assets
      |-CSS
      |-Fonts
      |-images
         |-logo
|-src
   |-Command
   |-Controller
   |-Entity
   |-Repository
   |-Resources
|-templates
   |-homepage
      |-index.html.twig
   base.html.twig
   header.html.twig
   footer.html.twig
```

Edit: I thought maybe this could be the reason somehow, the entire folder was inside my OneDrive. The thought crossed my mind, OneDrive is to blame. I don't know why, it's just a hunch...

Comment: Try checking the option "disable cache" in your browser's developer console. It might be http cache the issue.

Comment: Cache is disabled while the DevTools(Edge) are open, even trying an other browser doesn't make a difference.

Comment: have you tried with a different web server ? that could be helpful to narrow the issue

Comment: Post the code (all twig files and controller). Also post your directory tree. What output do you have?

Comment: It outputs an older version of the header and footer twig files, in which for example the logo file and folder had a capital. How can i post the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I just restarted the whole project. There were several other problems with it.
Although it would be interesting to see if anyone knows why the header an footer didn't change, it is not really relevant anymore.